# How to deny access to a folder with .htacces and openlitespeed

Tags: .htaccess, openlitespeed

How do I enable deny for a folder through htaccess with openlitespeed? I tried

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/folder/?$
```

and
`Deny from all`

But it didn't work, I still access the folder even after restart openlitespeed

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following in your htaccess file. This will forbid any URL whose uri starts with folder.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^folder - [F,L]
```